# How do i convert a varchar field to date

Tags: mysql

I have a dob attribute which is a varchar. Some of the dates are stored in format 6/6/2017 and some in format 2017-06-06. How do i convert those in format 6/6/2017 into 2017-06-06 and set the dob field as DATE datatype?

Answer (score 2):

For Your query you can write like this:

```
UPDATE table_name
    SET column1=DATE(STR_TO_DATE(column1, '%Y-%m-%d'))
    WHERE column1='"'.date('%d/%m/%Y',strtotime(column1)).'"'
```

and to set varchar to date datatype you can use CONVERT function or write like:

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wants to convert the D/M/YYYY date to YYYY-MM-DD permanently then add_new column having DATE datatype and update that column value by using this query

```
UPDATE TABLE tbl_name set format_dob= STR_TO_DATE(yourdatefield, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

If you just wants the calculated column then simply use

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(yourdatefield, '%m/%d/%Y') FROM tbl_name
```

Answer (score 1):

First update existing column to proper date format (YYYY-MM-DD) using

```
UPDATE tbl_name SET dob = STR_TO_DATE(dob,'%d/%m/%Y')
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(dob,'%d/%m/%Y') IS NOT NULL;
```

Once `Update` is completed `ALTER` the column to `DATE` datatype

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name MODIFY `dob` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00';
```

Comment: with the first query, it is giving null values.

Comment: Sorry, didn't look closely at your current date format. Have updated my POST. Please check it.